# How to Import data from Excel 2010 to SQL table

Tags: sql, excel, openrowset

I am using this ,

```
Insert into smst
(id,mobile,day,month,year,time,model,imie1,imie2,FullMessage)
select * 
FROM OPENROWSET
('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.14.0','Excel 14.0;Database=L:\SMS.xlsx;HDR=YES'
, 'SELECT id,mobile,day,month,year,time,model,imie1,imie2,FullMessage 
FROM [Sheet2]')
```

Could you please help and find the error?

sql error :

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.14.0','Excel 14.0;Database=L:\SMS.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT i' at line 1

i am using excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned `OPENROWSET` is a MSSQL-specific keyword and you seem to the using MySQL. Replace `select *FROM OPENROWSET` with `VALUES` and you should be good to go:

```
Insert into smst
(id,mobile,day,month,year,time,model,imie1,imie2,FullMessage) 
VALUES ('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.14.0','Excel 14.0;Database=L:\SMS.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
'SELECT id,mobile,day,month,year,time,model,imie1,imie2,FullMessage 
FROM [Sheet2]')
```

Comment: Values and select in the same insert query?  Unless that's a MySQL feature, it's not normally valid sql.

Comment: Note that the "SELECT id [..]" is a literal and not actually part of the query itself.

Comment: Thanks Dan & Simon,

Yes you right, i am using MY SQL, 

Dear , Actually, 
I have an excel data file and i working in MYSQL,
now the problem is!! this excel file daily receive 500 entries automatically. and i want to  update the SQL table automatically just by replacing the file excel file . 

What could be the best ways , pls suggest with an example

Thanks
Saleem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SQL Data Import wizard?  In SQL Server Right click on the DB and chose tasks-> Import and follow the prompts. You'll want to chose Excel as your source and depending on what you need you can create a new table, append the rows to an existing table, or write a custom query against the spreadsheet.  If creating a new table be careful on the datatypes as the wizard will try to best guess data types based on first 100 records but you can override this through the wizard to whatever data types you need.